# How to render the landing page in server and the rest in client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am fairly new to server-side rendering concepts. I am using react and I wanted to make only one page, i.e. the home page rendered in the server. After that, any action the user takes should be rendered on the client-side.

I am trying to build a single page application that fetches data from the database but on the first load, I want the server to send the rendered page to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to build e.g. an Express/Node app or a plain static website, where you then include the script generated with React (with `<script>` tags). I have done that before.

EDIT // Here's my project with both client and server side apps. [Link](https://github.com/mkkekkonen/graafit)

For example:

[A React component](https://github.com/mkkekkonen/graafit/blob/master/graphs/src/react/1_degreeVertexUndirected.jsx):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { AddEdge, AddNode } from '../components';

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { nodes, addNode, addEdge } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <AddNode
          addNodeCallback={addNode}
        />
        <AddEdge
          nodes={nodes}
          addEdgeCallback={addEdge}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const render = (nodes, addNode, addEdge) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Component
      nodes={nodes}
      addNode={addNode}
      addEdge={addEdge}
    />,
    document.getElementById('reactContainer'),
  );
};
```

[Server side code snippet](https://github.com/mkkekkonen/graafit/blob/master/server/src/index.js):

```
 app.get('/:categoryName/:pageName', async (req, res) => {
    const navData = await getNavData();
    const { categoryName, pageName } = req.params;

    const category = navData.categories
      .find(category => `${category.name}`.toLowerCase() === parseParam(categoryName));
    const page = navData.pages
      .find(page => `${page.name}`.toLowerCase() === parseParam(pageName));

    if (!category || !page) {
      res.render('notFound', { ...navData });
      return;
    }

    fs.readFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'content', 'md', `${category.id}_${page.templateFile}`),
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          res.render('error', { ...navData, message: err.message });
          return;
        }

        res.render('page', { ...navData, category, page, markdown: data.toString().replace(/\n/g, '\\n').replace(/\r/g, '') });
      }
    )
  });
```

[Server side HTML layout](https://github.com/mkkekkonen/graafit/blob/master/server/src/views/page.handlebars)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div id="md"></div>
      <div id="reactContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div id="graphContainer" class="graph-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.9.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var converter = new showdown.Converter();
  document.getElementById('md').innerHTML = converter.makeHtml('{{{markdown}}}');
</script>

<script src="{{urlBase}}/graphs/vendors.js"></script>
<script src="{{urlBase}}/graphs/{{category.id}}_{{page.jsFile}}"></script>
```

Comment: I added stuff about my example project

Comment: To be clear, the client side could be a single-page React app (or Angular, or Vue) and the server could be _anything_, not limited to node (the server could be Ruby, PHP, Java, C# etc)